# Counting Characters and Strings n C

Tags: arrays, c, string, character, declaration

This is one of the assignments for my class and this is the objective of the assignment:

> Write a program whose input is a character and a string, and whose output indicates the number of times the character appears in the string. The output should include the input character and use the plural form, ***n's***, if the number of times the characters appears is **not** exactly `1`. You may assume that the string does not contain spaces and will always contain less than 50 characters.

This is the code I have so far and I am new to C programming so I don't know how to declare Strings correctly just yet. So far I learned there are no strings in C like there is in Java and you have to do them as a character array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char userChar;
    char userString[50];
    int count = 0;
      
    for (int i = 0; i < userChar; i++) {
        if (userString[i] == userChar)
            count++;
    }
      
    printf("%d", count);
    if (count != 1)
        printf("'s");
      
    return 0;
}
```

For example, if I wanted to input `n Monday`   and output `1 n`

What would I need to change in my code to go from `n Monday` to `1 n`

This is the only output I am getting, and it only has outputted one thing correctly:

```
0's
```

Comment: Are you supposed to get the parameters as arguments to the program on the command line, or get them from stdin?

Comment: You need to get input. Have you been taught to do that? Your userChar and userString are not set.

Comment: your loop `for (int i = 0; i < userChar; i++) {` makes no sense,, you need to loop over the length of the string. Furthermore, you can hardcode values, like `char userChar = 's'; char userString[50] = "ThisIsATest";` to test the core logic until you determine where the program inputs will come from

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping. I see what I did wrong and I understand what I need to do now.

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope this is not considered cheating :-)

Second, you need to define userChar and userString as arguments for main, and pass them in at run time. They are assigned nothing, so that is why you get

`0's`

Third, your **for** condition is wrong. You need this so it only iterates through the length of the string:

`for (int i = 0; i < strlen(userString); i++)`

Finally, You are not printing the value of userChar prior to the return

Comment: "you need to define userChar and userString as arguments for main!" No, not the only option and phrased like that it is misleading or at least misunderstandable. But you are on a helpful track here. I recommend to wait for clarification of the input source/method and then go along the compromise described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to input a string and a character. To count the number of occurrences of the character in the string you can use standard string function `strchr`.

The program can look something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) 
{
    char userChar = ' ';
    char userString[50] = "";
  
    printf( "Enter a string without embedded spaces\nof the length less than %d: ", 50 );
    scanf( "%49s", userString );

    printf( "Enter a character to search in the string: " );
    scanf( " %c", &userChar );

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( const char *p = userString; ( p = strchr( p, userChar ) ) != NULL; ++p )
    {
        ++n;
    }
     
    printf( "%zu%s %c\n", n, n < 2 ? "" : "'s", userChar ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is not `0's`, it should include the counted character: for example if the character is `n` and the string `Monday`, the output should be

```
1 n
```

and if the string is `Eeny-meeny-miny-moe`, the output would be

```
3 n's
```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char userChar;
    char userString[50];
    int i, count;

    printf("Enter character: ");
    scanf(" %c", &userChar);
    printf("Enter string (single word): ");
    // read a word with at most 49 characters
    scanf(" %49s", userString);
    
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; userString[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (userString[i] == userChar)
            count++;
    }
      
    printf("%d %c", count, userChar);
    if (count != 1)
        printf("'s");
    printf("\n");
      
    return 0;
}
```